# 404 Not found while hitting api with Json token using postman

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am following this [Tutorial](https://fullstackmark.com/post/10/user-authentication-with-angular-and-asp-net-core) and on Securing a controller with claim based authorization part I am getting a **404 Not Found** error in Postman. I  have exactly followed the tutorial, i am just running .net core v2.0.0 .

Tutorial's DashboardController.cs is in my project named as BordViewController.cs .

This is my BordViewController.cs . The problem is, control is not going in this class, but when i remove `[Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]` it works.

```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DotNetGigs
{

    [Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BordViewController : Controller
    {       
        public BordViewController()
        {

        }

         // GET api/dashboard/home
        [HttpGet("home")]
        public IActionResult GetHome()
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(new { Message = "This is secure data!" });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my startup.cs file

```
private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));


        public Startup()
        {
            var builder  = new ConfigurationBuilder();            
            builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString(),"Configuration.json"));
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration {get;set;} 

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<AppDBcontext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),b=>b.MigrationsAssembly("LoginApp")));

           services.AddSingleton<IJWTfactory, JWTFactory>();

           var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));



            // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
            services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
                options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
                options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);});

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JWTclaimIden.Rol, Constants.Strings.JWTclaims.ApiAccess));
            });

            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
                {
                    // configure identity options
                    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBcontext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };


            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }).AddJwtBearer(options => 
                    {                   // options.Audience = Configuration.GetSection("TokenProviderOptions:Audience").Value;
                                        //options.Issuer = Configuration.GetSection("TokenProviderOptions:Issuer").Value;
                                        // options.SaveToken = true;
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    });

            services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
            services.AddAutoMapper();            
        }





        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }


           app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I am new to c# and .net core, if someone can help me figure out the mistake I am making I would be really grateful. Also please tell me if you want me to add some other files too.

Postman Code snippet

```
 GET /api/boardview/home HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:5000
    Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJuaWtoaWxrYTU4NUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJqdGkiOiJmMTc1ZjdiNy1iN2ZmLTQxM2UtYjM5Ny0yYTQyYmI3NjMxZmQiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDk1NTY2MzQsInJvbCI6ImFwaV9hY2Nlc3MiLCJpZCI6ImJlOWJmZjc5LThlNDEtNDEwYS1iN2E3LTBjOGQxNDExYjQ5YyIsIm5iZiI6MTUwOTU1NjYzNCwiZXhwIjoxNTA5NTYzODM0LCJpc3MiOiJMb2dpbkFwcCIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC8ifQ.NbwKHjH8h
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Postman-Token: 18e932c2-ac73-5539-60a1-04b7b981e37a
```

JwtIssureOptions

```
"JwtIssuerOptions": {
          "Issuer":"LoginApp",
          "Audience":"http://localhost:5000/"
      }
```

Comment: What does you request look like? :)

Comment: @cdslijngard I am sending a Get request to http://localhost:5000/api/boardview/home , with Authorization as a Header and Bearer xxx as it's value . xxx being JSON token

Comment: Can you post your cURL?

Comment: @Rogala I don't know how to do that and what exactly you want. Is there something in Postman I can post ?

Comment: Under the save button, there is a Code link.  Copy the texted and paste it in your question.  Remove any keys you don't want us to see.

Comment: @Rogala Added in the post

Comment: @Faye, try to replace [HttpGet("home")] to [Route("home")] in your GetHome()

Comment: @itikhomi No, still same problem.

Comment: My guess is you get a 404 because the `Authorize` decides you're not authorized and is redirecting you to something like Account/Login, which itself 404s.

Comment: @Faye, can you post response headers?

Comment: @Kirk Yes, it is redirecting me to Account/Login. Can you help me in this, upto the creation of JSON token i am getting 200 OK status.

Comment: Try setting this above your public API method. `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` (choose which you want.)

Comment: Please include the contents of `JwtIssuerOptions` from your `Configuration.json` file.

Comment: @Kirk included that in the end of question